# Как будем переводить ярлык "Watched"?

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, отслеживаемые-метки

После [недавних изменений](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375081/339911) дизайна, некоторые вопросы могут выглядеть так:

> [image: Watched]

Этот ярлык говорит о том, что вопрос содержит [отслеживаемую метку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/tag-notifications/current). Раньше здесь была просто фоновая подсветка вопроса. Но если оно останется в таком виде, то надо решить как его переводить. Очевидное "Отслеживается" может быть достаточно длинным и ещё больше вносить нарушение в дизайн. К тому же есть отдельный механизм [отслеживания (Following) сообщений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=following), что может привести к путанице.

Предлагаю обсудить возможные варианты перевода.

Comment: "под наблюдением"

Comment: кстати, забавно, что эта плашка относится скорее к метке в вопросе, чем к вопросу 

Comment: "В подписках" или "Интересное"

Comment: Или "Зацени" =D

Comment: Хм, у меня уже плашка пропала и вернулось выделение фона желтым

Comment: @Nofate, не прокатило - вычеркиваем :-D

Answer (score 1):

Переводить символом . или |, чтобы занимала как можно меньше места.